# ARC - Restructure app to prevent from crashing because of memory

Tags: objective-c, memory, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I ran into problems I can't find a solution for myself so I need your help. In the following I am going to explain my app structure and then explain my problem.

The RootViewController class manages the views that are visible on screen. In the viewDidLoad method of the RootViewController two other view controllers are being allocated. One is called DocumentViewer and is addable to the view as a modalViewController from everywhere in the app. The other one is called MapViewController and contains a view with a looping video, an image and a few buttons. Each of those buttons causes the MapViewController.view to be removed from RootViewController.view and another ViewController to be allocated in the RootViewController whos view is then added to the RootControllers view. I am gonna call those ViewControllers NewViewController for the sake of you being able to follow. This view switch is caused by a method called switchViews in the RootViewController.

The views controlled by the NewViewControllers now each contain a segmented control inside a navigation bar. Inside the viewDidLoad method of this ViewController four other viewControllers are being allocated, three of them containing a webView and a last one with five screen sized images. All are being stored in an array called viewArray. Each time the value of the segmented control is changed a method is called that removes all views in the array that have a superview, which is always only the one currently visible, and then adds the view as a subview that is stored in the viewArray at the index of the segmentedControl element, so segment with index 0 loads [viewArray objectAtIndex:0].
A button in the navigation bar calls the switchViews method in the RootViewController to remove the current view and add the MapViewController.view again.

So this is my application and as you may have guessed I am running into memory warning problems. For example when I am in a NewViewControllers view and call the DocumentViewer and load a pdf into it's webView I get a memory warning and the app crashes.

Since I am using ARC for the first time and I am also not very experienced in Objective-C I don't know where to set viewController allocations to nil or stuff like that to keep memory usage on an acceptable level.

Can anybody tell me where I need to make changes or unload content to prevent my app from crashing? Or maybe post a link to a tutorial explaining how to prevent issues like that?

Comment: @JeremyP using MRC != craziness. really, there's absolutely nothing wrong if somebody opts to do their own reference counting.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe It was only an advice. Please don't troll me.

Comment: @JeremyP no, I'm not. It's my personal opinion that ARC is much more confusing with all its weak vs. strong references, assignments to variables making programs crash or leak memory and not having the full control that (Objective-)C offers by default.

Comment: @H2CO3 you're welcome. i still use MRC (almost all the time). i think understanding MRC is necessary, even for people using ARC -- it's only one step of abstraction away.

Comment: @H2CO3 While I would absolutely agree that it is necessary to understand manual reference counting, ARC is just so much better for production code that you should really use it all the time.  You will get fewer memory leaks and crashes and you don't have retains/releases/autoreleases cluttering up your code.

Comment: @Justin exactly. Me too, I use MRC and my experience is that beginners who commence by using ARC immediately will have serious trouble understanding memory management because they lack knowledge of MRC.

Comment: @JeremyP you also are right (and I'm happy to see this comment of yours not being rude), but I know MRC well enough not to need ARC. MRC is easier for me to understand and do well, as I explained.

Comment: @H2CO3 My previous comment wasn't intended to be rude either.  Apologies if it read that way to you.  I also know MRC very well, but I no longer use it.

Comment: @JeremyP no worries then. I see your point.

Comment: in more detail: i had 'ARC' years before it existed. i simply acknowledged that this was a recurring complexity/source of problems/source of redundant implementations, and wrote my own C++ smart pointers. these classes of bugs disappeared (almost entirely) long ago. i use these smart pointers on most projects, otherwise i use MRC. of course, that's not available to people don't use ObjC++.

Answer (score 1):

ARC is not magic: only automatic. You still have to make sure that you don't have a retain cycle, or memory will never be reclaimed and you effectively have a leak if those objects can no longer be reached.

Answer (score 1):

a starting point would be to clear and remove views which are not visible.

as well, run with instruments so you understand where your allocations are coming from -- jump from view to view and look for growth or objects which aren't freed when you leave the view (heap shot analysis is good for this). in many cases, you should be able to navigate from a view and back without heap growth.

Comment: Just for my understanding. That means setting the variable containing the view to nil?

Comment: it could be views, or pdfs, movies, etc which are not visible. or you might just want to focus on big things which can be quickly reloaded at first; displayed pdfs, large images, and such.